# MailChimp for Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, mailchimp

I am following these directions: https://mailchimp.com/help/connect-or-disconnect-mailchimp-for-magento/

The site is running `Magento 1.9.3.2`, I'm a PHP developer, but haven't used Magento before, it's hosted by magemojo.com.

I've followed the directions but when I visit "`Configuration`" there is no Mailchimp configuration menu.

I've copied the files into their corresponding folders, I've checked the permissions, I've cleared the cache, I've re-uploaded the files, I've logged out and logged back in. I've done all of these things multiple times.

The Magento Connect Manager `404's` which I think might have been intentional for security reasons, but I can't figure out how exactly.

I'm not sure exactly what to try next, so any help would be great. I've backed up the site and have ftp (`port 21`) access to the site. It doesn't look like it uses source control, but I've put my back up in git and have commits before and after installing **MailChimp**.

Comment: I'll try to help you, you tell `I've copied the files into their corresponding folders,` you did them really correctly? where I can find these files to download them ?

Comment: the files can be downloaded by following the directions here: https://mailchimp.com/help/connect-or-disconnect-mailchimp-for-magento/

Answer (score 1):

First check if you have MageMonkey installed, by navigate to `app/etc/modules`, looking for `Ebizmarts_MageMonkey.xml`. If yes, uninstall Ebizmarts_MageMonkey, here is the [link](https://ebizmarts.com/forums/topics/view/19381).

Then, re-install MailChimp for Magento, remember to flush the cache, log out and log back in to see the changes.

Comment: Thanks! MageMonkey is not installed, I see an Ebizmarts_MailChimp.xml but no Ebizmarts_MageMonkey.xml

Comment: Remove that Ebizmarts_MailChimp extension, it should work.

Answer (score -1):

Before installing mailchimp or any extension you have to make sure that Compilation must be disabled.

```
Go to admin > System > Tools > Compilation and check compilation enable or not.
```

Comment: it is disabled.

`Compiler Status Disabled

Compilation State Not Compiled

Collected Files Count 0

Compiled Scopes Count 0`